# Compile error when union case has same name as type

Tags: f#

In this example on the last line, I want to create an instance of the type `A` but I get a compile error. When I hover over `A("A1")` I can see that `A` is taken to refer to the union case `TM.A` and not the type `A`. Can anyone explain what the compiler is doing here and how to avoid this error without needing to change the name of the union case (I'd like it to be the same as the type name)

```
type A(name:string)
    = member this.Name = name

type T(name:string)
    = member this.Name = name

type TK(t:T, a:List<A>) =
    member this.T = t
    member this.A = a

type TM =
    | T of T 
    | A of A 
    | G of List<T>

let a = A("A1")
```

Comment: Besides the answer by 3615, you could also specify the full name of the type, e.g. if this is in MyModule, do `let a = MyModule.A("A1")`. That should be another way to disambiguate between the type and the DU case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the easiest way would be just calling it with new, like `new A("A1")`.